# Shear flow for unequal leg channel

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, beam, solid-mechanics

How does the sine part i.e. $\dfrac{\ell\sin(\theta)}{2}$ appear in the calculation of shear flow ($q$)? I mean, if I'm not mistaken, the sine part is the distance from the x-axis to point D, but how is it derived?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation you are showing concerns the shear force in the top flange. The shear stress is calculated at a horizontal distance of $l$ from B. To use Zhuravskii's shear stress formula, you need the first moment of area of that part of the top flange with length $l$. It has an area of $tl$ and its centroid has a distance to the $X$-axis of the distance from the axis to B, $|Y_B|$, plus the distance from B to the center of the bit of flange measured parallel to the $Y$-axis, i. e. $\frac{1}{2}l\sin\theta$. So that gives a term of $tl\left(|Y_B|+\frac{1}{2}l\sin\theta\right)$